# Find the correct sign

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

This is a question in a primary school book as a riddle.

> How can we put *any mathematical sign* (addition , subtraction, multiply and division) between five 5s to get the answer 66?
>
> 5 5 5 5 5=66

Comment: As written, without [Lukasian gyrations](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45972/30633) of interpretation this puzzle has no solutions: no single operator can be placed, once or multiple times, between any or all the digits to create an expression that evaluates to 66.  Allowing for more than one operator, and for digits to be combined (without an operator between them) into multi-digit numbers, gives [Techidiot's solution](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45970/30633), but that's not how this question reads. What exactly did you intend this question to ask?

Comment: If there is a trick, then you may wish to include the [lateral-thinking] tag.

Answer (score 7):

I guess it is this -

> 55/5+55=66

Answer (score 1):

The obvious and trivial answer is

> $55+5+5+5$, when calculating in Base 14
> You notice how it says *"Find the correct sign"* and *"any mathematical sign"*? So we're only allowed to use *one* mathematical sign of {+,-,*,/} to fill in the blanks. It's also clear that we have to use Base 14 since $6+5$ in Base 7 equals $14$. Why 7? Because it's the lowest base where $5$ and $6$ are included.

---

;)

Comment: Can you explain how "since 6 + 5 in Base 7 equals 14" is relevant here? Can you explain how "it's the lowest base where 5 and 6 are included" is relevant here?

Comment: @IanMacDonald It's a clue that indicates what base to use for the calculation.

Comment: It's a "clue" that you arbitrarily introduced and was not part of the puzzle. An equivalent clue could be "55555 in base 6 is actually 7775 in base 10, therefore, we should treat the words as having full permissions to read, write and execute". Please explain how you have made the leap more precisely.

Comment: First he did some warm-up stretches. Then he carefully judged the distance. Then he aligned himself *just so*, gauged the prevailing winds, and lined himself up at the near edge at the most advantageous angle. Next, he made the appropriate signs, gestures, and/or supplications to ${DEITY-the Universe}. And finally, knees bent, arms braced, and with feet firmly planted on ground and tongue firmly planted in cheek, he let fly.